# Selenium Remote Control

Tags: java, selenium

Hy.

I have a problem running selenium tests with Selenium Remote control.

After I open a console windows and type the following command :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.2.0.jar -htmlsuite *firefox http://book.theautomatedtester.co.uk "c:\Users\abc\Desktop\Selenium\selenium-remote-control\testsuite.html" "c:\Users\abc\Desktop\Selenium\selenium-remote-control\result.html"
```

firefox is starting

but my test don't run and in the console it say´s: Checking resource aliases (it is stuck)

Could somebody help me with this problem please? :)

Thank you

Comment: Syntax is fine - could you post your test cases?

Answer (score 0):

You probably referenced your Selenium Test Case html file, not your Test Suite html file.  Try creating a Test Suite, and adding your Test Case to that file.  Then reference the Test Suite file path as your test suite argument when calling your command.